# Cold Crashing techniques

Tags: techniques, cold-crash, cold

I have very nearly mastered the clarification process but still wish to control the timing of flocculation more consistently.  At what point/stage is cold crashing most efficient?

Comment: I assume we are talking about beer and not wine?

Comment: I would suggest winter.  :-D

Answer (score 9):

I give fermentation 4-5 days at 63°F, then bump up the temp to 70-72°F for maybe another 3 days.  Then I crash to 33°F for 3-5 days until the beer clears.

Comment: its October, I just leave mine outside by the side door for a couple of nights and it has cleared beautifully

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure exactly what you are defining as efficient, so I am going to answer this assuming time efficiency is your primary goal.

Denny's advice is good advice for a general approach without having to faff around checking things, and will ferment all but the largest brews to FG.

I would suggest you take daily samples and gravity readings.  As soon as you have 2 of the same readings, then I would start the crashing process for optimal time efficiency. You can cold crash down to -1°C/30°F, as the alcohol and sugars in solution will prevent freezing, but you should be aiming for 33-38°F/0.5-3.5°C.